# /system/etc/ld.config.version_identifier.txt not found and how to check for VNDK compliancy

Tags: rom-flashing

I need to flash using a Generic System Image (GSI) but when I'm checking if my device is  Vendor Native Development Kit (VNDK) complaint as per the documentation here https://developer.android.com/topic/generic-system-image#device-compliance it says

> Check for cross-version support by running the following command:
>
> adb shell cat /system/etc/ld.config.version_identifier.txt 
> | grep -A 20 "[vendor]"

This file doesn't exist on my Google Pixel (1 aka Sailfish) or my Google Pixel 2 XL (taimen).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of the path `/system/etc/ld.config.version_identifier.txt`

On Google Pixel 1 (Sailfish) use `/system/etc/ld.config.vndk_lite.txt` - this probably will work for other devices on Android 10 and below.

**Android 11** including (Google Pixel 2 XL (taimen)) use `/linkerconfig/ld.config.txt` instead as per https://source.android.com/devices/architecture/vndk/linker-namespace